# WIFI connection unstable - keeps dropping and reconnecting on archlinux

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, iw

Today my laptop started randomly experiencing issues where it cannot maintain a stable connection on my home network for more than 30s.

I have tried the following w/out success...

(1) Killing wpa_supplicant

(2) Removing `wpa_supplicant.conf`

(2) Upgrading pacman

(3) Turning powersaving for wifi off ([source][1])

(4) Restarting NetworkManager

(5) Setting `interval=0` in NetworkManager.conf ([source][2])

(6) Disabling ipv6 connectivity -- not ideal ([source][3])

(7) `ip link set wlp59s0 up/down`

Some system information...

I am using a Dell XPS 15 9570 with original specs.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp59s0   IEEE <IEEE>  ESSID: <SSID>
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 24:F5:A2:7F:91:2E
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-35 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:138   Missed beacon:0
```

```
$ systemctl list-units --type service --no-pager
  UNIT                                                LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
  alsa-restore.service                                loaded active exited  Save/Restore Sound Card State
  bluetooth.service                                   loaded active running Bluetooth service
  cups.service                                        loaded active running CUPS Scheduler
  dbus.service                                        loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
  kmod-static-nodes.service                           loaded active exited  Create List of Static Device Nodes
  ldconfig.service                                    loaded active exited  Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache
  lightdm.service                                     loaded active running Light Display Manager
  lvm2-monitor.service                                loaded active exited  Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dm…
  NetworkManager.service                              loaded active running Network Manager
  polkit.service                                      loaded active running Authorization Manager
  rtkit-daemon.service                                loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service
  systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:…
  systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service  loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:dell:…
  systemd-binfmt.service                              loaded active exited  Set Up Additional Binary Formats
  systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b9e8c21\x2d9d18\… loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/2b9e8c21-9d1…
  systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d5705268\x2d6bfe\… loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d5705268-6bf…
  systemd-journal-catalog-update.service              loaded active exited  Rebuild Journal Catalog
  systemd-journal-flush.service                       loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
  systemd-journald.service                            loaded active running Journal Service
  systemd-logind.service                              loaded active running User Login Management
  systemd-modules-load.service                        loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules
  systemd-random-seed.service                         loaded active exited  Load/Save OS Random Seed
  systemd-remount-fs.service                          loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
  systemd-sysctl.service                              loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables
  systemd-sysusers.service                            loaded active exited  Create System Users
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service            loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev gracefully
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                  loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                      loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories
  systemd-udev-trigger.service                        loaded active exited  Coldplug All udev Devices
  systemd-udevd.service                               loaded active running Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
  systemd-update-done.service                         loaded active exited  Update is Completed
  systemd-update-utmp.service                         loaded active exited  Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP
  systemd-user-sessions.service                       loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions
  systemd-vconsole-setup.service                      loaded active exited  Virtual Console Setup
  udisks2.service                                     loaded active running Disk Manager
  user-runtime-dir@1000.service                       loaded active exited  User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000
  user@1000.service                                   loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000
  wpa_supplicant.service                              loaded active running WPA supplicant

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
38 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

```
$ find /etc/systemd -type l -exec test -f {} \; -print | awk -F'/' '{ printf ("%-40s | %s\n", $(NF-0), $(NF-1)) }' | sort -f
bluetooth.service                        | bluetooth.target.wants
cups.path                                | multi-user.target.wants
cups.service                             | multi-user.target.wants
cups.service                             | printer.target.wants
cups.socket                              | sockets.target.wants
dbus-org.bluez.service                   | system
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service | system
display-manager.service                  | system
fstrim.timer                             | timers.target.wants
gcr-ssh-agent.socket                     | sockets.target.wants
getty@tty1.service                       | getty.target.wants
gnome-keyring-daemon.socket              | sockets.target.wants
NetworkManager-wait-online.service       | network-online.target.wants
NetworkManager.service                   | multi-user.target.wants
p11-kit-server.socket                    | sockets.target.wants
pipewire.socket                          | sockets.target.wants
pulseaudio.socket                        | sockets.target.wants
remote-fs.target                         | multi-user.target.wants
```

```
$ journalctl --grep=wl
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8851] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: inter>
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8853] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp59s0 cr>
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8861] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P de>
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8867] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): state change: unmanaged ->
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8882] device (wlp59s0): state change: unavailable -> disc>
Sep 16 16:55:43 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908543.8896] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): state change: unavailable>
Sep 16 16:55:44 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:44 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:44 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:44 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:47 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:47 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4922] device (wlp59s0): Activation: starting connection '>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4923] device (wlp59s0): state change: disconnected -> pre>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4927] device (wlp59s0): state change: prepare -> config (>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4929] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4929] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> need-auth>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4936] device (wlp59s0): state change: need-auth -> prepar>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4938] device (wlp59s0): state change: prepare -> config (>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.4940] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'bu>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b (SSID='SSID>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: authenticate with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5434] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disco>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5434] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management int>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b (SSID='SSID' freq=5>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5443] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authe>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5443] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management int>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: send auth to b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b (try 1/3)
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: authenticated
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: associate with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b (try 1/3)
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=23)
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: Associated with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: associated
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5550] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: assoc>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5550] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management int>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5769] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: assoc>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.5770] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management int>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b [PTK=CCMP GTK=>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 wpa_supplicant[68429]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b completed [id>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp59s0: link becomes ready
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 kernel: wlp59s0: Limiting TX power to 24 (24 - 0) dBm as advertised by b8:f8:53:8c:4a:3b
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6315] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6316] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6316] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management int>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6320] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> ip-config>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6333] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction >
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6585] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed new lease, address=1>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6593] policy: set 'SSID' (wlp59s0) as default for I>
Sep 16 16:55:48 arch082022 NetworkManager[68359]: <info>  [1694908548.6734] device (wlp59s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-che>
...skipping...
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.2920] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   address fd45:b24>
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.2920] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fdb8:783:a>
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.2920] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd56:ab5d:>
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.2921] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd45:b248:>
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.2922] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: solicit: schedule >
Sep 16 18:35:21 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914521.8022] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3149] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3150] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: received rout>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3150] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: router-data: next >
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3150] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: neighbor discovery>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3150] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   dhcp-level none
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3151] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   address fd45:b24>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3151] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fdb8:783:a>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3151] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd56:ab5d:>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3151] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd45:b248:>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3152] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: solicit: schedule >
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3156] platform: (wlp59s0) address: adding or updating IPv>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.3157] platform: (wlp59s0) signal: address 6 changed: fd45>
Sep 16 18:35:22 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914522.5197] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:23 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914523.4413] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:24 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914524.4644] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3863] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3864] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: received rout>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3864] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: router-data: next >
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3864] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: neighbor discovery>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3865] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   dhcp-level none
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3865] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   address fd45:b24>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3865] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fdb8:783:a>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3865] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd56:ab5d:>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3866] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd45:b248:>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3867] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: solicit: schedule >
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3871] platform: (wlp59s0) address: adding or updating IPv>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.3872] platform: (wlp59s0) signal: address 6 changed: fd45>
Sep 16 18:35:25 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914525.5910] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:26 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914526.4110] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:27 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914527.4346] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3566] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3567] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: received rout>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3567] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: router-data: next >
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3568] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: neighbor discovery>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3568] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   dhcp-level none
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3568] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   address fd45:b24>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3568] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fdb8:783:a>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3569] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd56:ab5d:>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3569] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]:   route fd45:b248:>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3570] ndisc[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: solicit: schedule >
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3576] platform: (wlp59s0) address: adding or updating IPv>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.3577] platform: (wlp59s0) signal: address 6 changed: fd45>
Sep 16 18:35:28 arch082022 NetworkManager[26723]: <debug> [1694914528.5614] ndisc-lndp[0x558d79921700,"wlp59s0"]: processing li>
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake LPC Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation XG5 NVMe SSD Controller
```

```
$ inxi
CPU: 6-core Intel Core i7-8750H (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 800/800/4100 MHz
Kernel: 6.5.3-arch1-1 x86_64 Up: 1h 27m Mem: 3.56/15.27 GiB (23.3%)
Storage: 238.47 GiB (41.7% used) Procs: 269 Shell: Zsh inxi: 3.3.29
```

My `NetworkManager.conf` is...

```
# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[connectivity]
interval=0


[logging]
level=DEBUG
```

Additionally the contents of my `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dchp-client.conf` is (all done today to try and resolve things)...

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf
[main]
dhcp=dhclient

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi-powersave-off.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi_backend.conf
[device]
wifi.backend=iwd
```

After the change of the wifi backend to `iw`, after which I followed the steps to modify my existing profiles, but now it says that `wlp59s0` is unavailable and I cannot connect to anything.